# flutter path_provider never shows the path to my sdcard

Tags: android, flutter, path-provider

I just tried the example from path_provider github and this function : getExternalStorageDirectories() return the path: /storage/emulated/0/ etc... but never /storage/xxx-xxx/ etc relative to my sdcard
How can I get the sdcard path ?

on android phone with android studio flutter dart

I tried other packages without result ...

Comment: If a second item returned by getExternalFilesDirs() exists you are in luck. Otherwise use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: it seems to return a List ...

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is in kotlin ? I work with flutter / dart I don't know how to use it

Comment: getExternalFilesDirs() relurns an array.

Comment: an array or a list is for more than one element

Comment: package:path_provider/path_provider.dart Future<List<Directory>?> getExternalStorageDirectories({StorageDirectory? type})